# How to fix 'Unhandled promise rejection' when sending an email using Nodemailer via Gmail

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send an email using Nodemailer and Node.js but when I try to send the email, I am getting this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>
> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
>   64.233.188.109:465
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14) (node:8876)
>
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection.
>
> This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)

Here is my app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const path = require("path");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const app = express();

// View engine setup
app.engine("handlebars", exphbs());
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

// Static folder
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact");
});

app.post("/send", async (req, res) => {
  const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
        <li>Company: ${req.body.company}</li>
        <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
        <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>    
    `;

  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "from@mail.com",
      pass: "myPassword"
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: "from@mail.com", // sender address
    to: "to@mail.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "Test email", // Subject line
    html: output // plain text body
  };

  let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
  console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

  res.render("contact", { msg: "Email has been sent" });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server started..."));
```

Here is the body of my *contact.handlebars*:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="brand"><span>Acme</span> Web Design</h1>
    <div class="wrapper animated bounceInLeft">
        <div class="company-info">
            <h3>Acme Web Design</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><i class="fa fa-road"></i> 44 Something st</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (555) 555-5555</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> test@acme.test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
            <h3>Email Us</h3>
            {{ msg }}
            <form method="POST" action="send">
                <p>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Company</label>
                    <input type="text" name="company">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone">
                </p>
                <p class="full">
                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
                </p>
                <p class="full">
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code? Also, am I using the correct values in my createTransport() method?

Comment: your server is offline or unavailable, hence why you get an `ETIMEDOUT`, which is a timeout

Comment: Hi @messerbill, but I run the server & can navigate to localhost:3000 which displays the webpage

Comment: can you post the code where the request is sent?

Comment: ah i see - `res.render("contact", { msg: "Email has been sent" });` is not correct - try `res.send({ msg: "Email has been sent" });` instead

Comment: I've tried the above change, but I'm unfortunately receiving the same error message

Comment: can you debug your server code and have a look, if the request handler is called at all?

Comment: I haven't debugged in VS code before so don't know what steps are involved

Comment: @messerbill I put a try/catch around `var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport()` to see if that would make a difference, but the previous error message is still being displayed